# What's the right way to call an action from a different controller in ASP.Net MVC 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm getting a

> No route matches the supplied values

while trying to return a `RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller")`. The method signature says "actionName" and "ControllerName". I'm assuming actionName is the method name in the Controller, Am I correct? For ControllerName I'm using the Controller File Name without the Controller Sufix. Ex.:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "WebApp")
```

where `Index` is a method of `WebAppController` and the command is being issued from a method of `AnotherController`

Both the caller controller and the called one are on the same Controllers directory on the same application.

I'm cofused because in this ASP.net MVC application there is also `Route` attributes and `Action` attributes where you can put names on methods, different than the real method name. In my case I have no `Route["Name"]` nor `[httpXXX("route", Name="dasdasdas")]` configured for the methods involved in my attempt.

I have been reading MS docs and some examples but It appears I'm doing the thing right but for strange reasons it's not working. I even tried using `Redirect("Controller/Action")` and with it the problem vanishes but the new problem is this way of redirect doesn't support passing data parameters to the target route.

At this point I'm not working with Action links in Views, different from Form related ones.

I would really appreciate if at least anyone can give me a hint about where can I find info.

Comment: Your assumptions about `RedirectToAction` are correct. Do you have a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: Not at this moment but let me work on it an I'll post it back ASAP. Thank you.

Comment: It's 11pm in the evening here, so I'll pick it up in the morning if no one else does :-)

Comment: Doing the MCVE was helpful to validate that the error was not reproducible in other project. I spend many hours dissecting the troublesome project and finally found the error. It was something completely trivial. I'll update the post or answer the question with the root cause and simple solution. Thank you @NikolaiDante for your tip to remember the basics about problem solving :)

Answer (score 0):

The right way to call an action from a different controller is the one I was using:

`return RedirectToAction("AnActionMethodName", "AControllerWithoutControllerSufix"[, object values]);`

My problem, after several hour spent was that I added two `useMvc` calls in the `Startup.Configure(...)`method:

```
app.UseMvc();

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=MyApp}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

This was due to **copy + paste** of code. It was obviously confusing the MVC component in charge of attending the redirection part, as the right way I supose is tho use only one. (I'm newbie on .Net Platform and its frameworks)

Anyway I leave this as a reminder about the risks and consequences of copying and pasting code. At some point something weird can happen to your app and the cause can be a *simple* **copy + paste** error.